# compare array data and get an merged output in php

Tags: php, arrays, comparison, array-merge

I have an array like this. I want remove elements with duplicate id and get sum of the count

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["Count"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["Count"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }[2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["Count"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

and I need to remove elements with duplicate id and get sum of the count as shown below

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["Count"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }[1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["Count"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
```

}

I have gone through many examples.. but couldn't find an answer..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way around looping.  Assuming that `Name` is the same for the same `Id` or that you don't care about the value of `Name`:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    if(!isset($result[$value['Id']])) {
        $result[$value['Id']] = $value;
    } else {
        $result[$value['Id']]['Count'] += $value['Count'];
    }
}
// re-index if needed
$result = array_values($result);
```

- Loop the array and build result array using `Id` as key
- If the key `Id` doesn't exist create it
- If it does exist add `Count` to the current `Count`

Answer (score 0):

just create a new array, loop through current, create if doesnt exist, and insert values (sum) into new one

what are you doing with duplicates names?

example below. hope it will help.

```
<?php

    $tArr = array(
        array(
            "Id" => "1",
            "Name" => "a",
            "Count" => "2",
        ),
        array(
            "Id" => "2",
            "Name" => "b",
            "Count" => "1",
        ),
        array(
            "Id" => "1",
            "Name" => "a",
            "Count" => "1",
        )
    );

    $rez = array();


    foreach ($tArr as $key => $element) {
        if (empty($rez[$element["Id"]])) {
            $rez[$element["Id"]] = $element;
        } else {
            $rez[$element["Id"]]["Count"] += $element["Count"];
        }
    }

    var_dump($rez);


/** array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'Name' => string 'a' (length=1)
      'Count' => int 3
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'Name' => string 'b' (length=1)
      'Count' => string '1' (length=1)**/
```

Comment: Very similar to @abracadaver's answer.  Could they be combined?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$result = array_diff_assoc($arr, array_unique($arr));
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Did you try it yourself?  Doesn't work.  From Php array_unique man page notes: `Note: Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.`, also array_diff_assoc won't help, and you are not doing the count part of the question.